# How to use Typescript with Laravel Mix and Vue SFC?

Tags: laravel, typescript, vue.js, laravel-mix

Is it possible to use Typescript in Vue single file components (SFC) when using Laravel Mix?

If so, how should this be set up?

I'm currently using Laravel Mix 5.0, Typescript 3.7.5 and Vue 2.5.17.

I have a single file component written in Typescript, e.g. `SingleFileComponent.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul
        v-for="item in items"
        v-bind:key="item.id">
        <li>{{ item.message }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    Axios.get('/api/get-stuff').then(res => {
      this.items = res.data;
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

This is what I have configured in `webpack.mix.js`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.ts('resources/js/app.ts', 'public/js')
   .webpackConfig({
      resolve: {
         extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".vue", ".ts", ".tsx"]
       }
   });
```

Running `npm run watch` results in the following error:

```
ERROR in /path-to-file/SingleFileComponent.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /path-to-file/SingleFileComponent.vue.ts(21,12)
  TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type '{ data(): { items: never[]; }; mounted(): void; }'.
```

Answer (score 0):

When using SFC with Typescript you should `extend`:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Axios from 'axios';
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  ...
})
</script>
```